# Create True VLAN over RAS

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, vlan

I was wondering if it's possible.

I want to create a virtual network over RAS using Windows Server 2003.

The Client should be able to connect to the server using L2TP and should get an IP Adress from a private Range (lets say 192.168.1.100 - 192.168.1.200 and a subnetmask of 255.255.255.0).
Now each client connected to the server should be able to ping another connected client.

e.g. 192.168.1.123 <-> 192.168.1.145 via RAS via the server.

Is this possible? And ... how ?

best regards,
andre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible. You just have to add a static address pool on the IPV4 address assignment. Will your clients be able to access the server network segment or just this DMZ ? If so, you need to route the clients to the servers segment cause they will be put on a different network segment. Regards.

Comment: Just the DMZ. What about broadcast ? My Plan is to have something like hamachi but with Windows internal Tools

Comment: The broadcast address will be at your RAS server, and yes, this should be something like hamachi.